# Variable in bash array name

Tags: arrays, bash

I have this code:

```
#!/bin/sh

...

for cnumber in `seq $CNUMBER`; do
    declare -a CAT$cnumber
    let i=0
    while IFS=$'\n' read -r line_data; do
        CAT$cnumber[i]="${line_data}"
        ((++i))
    done < input_file_$cnumber
done
```

It works if I use array name without variable $cnumber.

But I want to create multiple arrays (CAT0, CAT1, CAT2 etc.) and to read lines:

> from file 'input_file_0' to array 'CAT0'
>   from file 'input_file_1' to array 'CAT1'
>   from file 'input_file_2' to array 'CAT2'
>   etc.

What syntax to use `$cnumber` variable in array name (CAT1) and in input file_name?

Comment: Try to concat the number i.e CAT{$cnumber}. Let me know if it is working

Comment: I think you mean `CAT${cnumber}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for cnumber in `seq $CNUMBER`; do
    declare -a CAT$cnumber
    let i=0
    while IFS=$'\n' read -r line_data; do
        eval CAT$cnumber[i]='"${line_data}"'
        ((++i))
    done < input_file_$cnumber
done
```

Mainly, that adds the word "eval" which makes bash evaluate the rest of the line. Before that, bash expands variables, thus CAT$number will be something like CAT1 when the line is evaluated. Keep in mind that "${line_date}" would be subject to variable expansion before eval evaluates the line if it would not be protected by single quotes. That might have unexpected effects if the $line_data would contain blank spaces. See this simplified example:

```
a=b
l="hello date"
eval $a="$l"    # executes "date", has no other effect
echo $b         # prints an empty line
eval $a='"$l"'  # sets b to "hello date"
echo $b         # prints that: hello date
```

In reply to the comment of **Etan Reisner** below, I add another solution that **avoids "eval"** and instead uses references, which are available in bash version 4.3 or higher. In that case, using references is preferable for the reason Etan pointed out, and also, for my opinion, because it is more natural:

```
for cnumber in `seq $CNUMBER`; do
    declare -a CAT$cnumber      # be sure the array is declared before ...
    declare -n ref=CAT$cnumber  # ... you declare ref to reference the array
    let i=0
    while IFS=$'\n' read -r line_data; do
        ref[$i]="${line_data}"
        ((++i))
    done < input_file_$cnumber
done
```

Comment: It should be pointed out that using `eval` has serious security implications unless variables are controlled **very** carefully. And given this snippet unless the `CAT##` arrays need to persist beyond the loop using a constructed variable name like this is likely entirely pointless. Also an indirect reference here would likely work as well and be safer.

Answer (score 0):

First, your shebang needs to be

```
#!/bin/bash
```

since `declare` is a bash built-in.

Next, use `declare` to define the array elements

```
for cnumber in `seq $CNUMBER`; do
    declare -a CAT$cnumber
    let i=0
    while IFS=$'\n' read -r line_data; do
        declare "CAT$cnumber[$i]=${line_data}"
        ((++i))
    done < input_file_$cnumber
done
```